# The KML file included in google drive that does not recognize

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have tried Displaying KML files in my google Maps application. I used [google map api documentation for that.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/kml#overviewhttps://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/kml#overview)

when I load my HTML file, it show only google map. I think this problem about KML file. How do i fix it ..? I have upload KML file into my google drive and I share it as "anyone with the link can edit". 
However Google Maps API's example is working...!!

this is the code :-

```
<script>
var map;
var src = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5oAxCVEQK5uZ0tJcFBDaGRfajg';

 function initialize() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.742291, 80.529785),
     zoom: 7,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });
 loadKmlLayer(src, map);
 }

  var kmlUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5oAxCVEQK5uZ0tJcFBDaGRfajg';
 var kmlOptions = {
 suppressInfoWindows: true,
 preserveViewport: false,
 map: map
  };
 var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);

function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
        var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
        var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
        testimonial.innerHTML = content;
    });}
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
```

Comment: use [`https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B5oAxCVEQK5uZ0tJcFBDaGRfajg`](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B5oAxCVEQK5uZ0tJcFBDaGRfajg)

Comment: Thank you, it's work for me. .(y), How did you save the kml file in google docs....

Comment: I did not save it, it's your file(note the id-parameter, it's the same as in your URL)....I called it via another URL(the URL you've used opens the KML-viewer, but you must link directly to the KML-file to get the correct headers)

Comment: Got it, thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for the question. This whole code is correct, and also kml file is correct. 
The point is, we are unable to put kml file in google Drive or Dropbox. you must host the KML file on a server. for that you can use [Google Sites to host Your KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/pagesforkml#introduction).

May be useful  :-   [Display KML in a Google Map](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/40) and below google api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/kml#overview