# KML layer not loading

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm trying to load a simple KML layer on a Google Map. I cannot make it work for a specific layer, while, at the same time, other similar KML layers load fine. Here is the minimal version of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/eundas/0fhqmocv/4/ Why does this not work? Is it something with my code or with the structure of the KML? I would appreciated any light on this.

```
var map;
var options = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5, -70),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  scaleControl: true
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), options);

var Coquimbo4204Layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bCBH784phTY_wK0WZiAbbDRlXb1dJsv7'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(Coquimbo4204Layer, 'status_changed', function() {
console.log(Coquimbo4204Layer.getStatus());
})
Coquimbo4204Layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: This KML file has access permissions for anybody with the link. Is there any way to find out what is stopping fiddle to fetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the posted code, I get [`FETCH_ERROR`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/kml#KmlLayerStatus.FETCH_ERROR), which according to the documentation means: `The document could not be fetched`.

It works if the url is `http:` rather than `https:` (that seems to be an issue with Google Drive).

Related questions:

- [The KML file included in google drive that does not recognize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492260/the-kml-file-included-in-google-drive-that-does-not-recognize)
- [KML not shown when loaded with javascript API to google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166722/kml-not-shown-when-loaded-with-javascript-api-to-google-maps)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y71jxod6/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var options = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5, -70),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  scaleControl: true
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), options);

var Coquimbo4204Layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    // url: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bCBH784phTY_wK0WZiAbbDRlXb1dJsv7'
    url: 'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bCBH784phTY_wK0WZiAbbDRlXb1dJsv7'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(Coquimbo4204Layer, 'status_changed', function() {
console.log(Coquimbo4204Layer.getStatus());
})
Coquimbo4204Layer.setMap(map);
```

```css
#mapcanvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="mapcanvas">CANVAS</div>
```